# Memory Usage, Filling Pandas DataFrame using Dict vs using key and value Lists

Tags: python, performance, list, pandas, dictionary

I am making a package that reads a binary file and returns data that can be used to initialize a `DataFrame`, I am now wondering if it is best to return a `dict` or two lists (one that holds the keys and one that holds the values).

The package I am making is not supposed to be entirely reliant on a `DataFrame` object, which is why my package currently outputs the data as a `dict` (for easy access). If there could be some memory and speed savings (which is paramount for my application as I am dealing with millions of data points), I would like to output the key and value lists instead. These iterables would then be used to initialize a `DataFrame`.

Here is a simple example:

```
In [1]: d = {(1,1,1): '111',
   ...: (2,2,2): '222',
   ...: (3,3,3): '333',
   ...: (4,4,4): '444'}

In [2]: keyslist=[(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3),(4,4,4)]

In [3]: valslist=['111','222','333','444']

In [4]: import pandas as pd

In [5]: dfdict=pd.DataFrame(d.values(),  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys(), names=['a','b','c']))

In [6]: dfdict
Out[6]: 
         0
a b c     
3 3 3  333
2 2 2  222
1 1 1  111
4 4 4  444

In [7]: dflist=pd.DataFrame(valslist,  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(keyslist, names=['a','b','c']))

In [8]: dfpair
Out[8]: 
         0
a b c     
1 1 1  111
2 2 2  222
3 3 3  333
4 4 4  444
```

It is my understanding that `d.values()` and `d.keys()` is creating a new ***copy*** of the data. If we disregard the fact the a `dict` takes more memory then a `list`, does using `d.values()` and `d.keys()` lead to more memory usage then the `list` pair implementation?

Comment: Why not use numpy arrays instead? They have a much lower memory footprint than both lists and dictionaries

Comment: I am not using numpy since I do not know the size of the data, so I have to populate a list or a dict, and then initialize a numpy array or pandas Dataframe.

Comment: I will write a benchmark of memory usage of lists vs dicts

Comment: Doesn't this also depend on the datatypes -- str, int and floats..

Comment: You can directly convert your dict to a DataFrame with `dfdict = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')`

Comment: The data in the dict is almost all floats, also I tried using `from_dict` but unfortunately multiindexing won't work.

Comment: Using `from_dict` will read the index in as tuples, but you can just create a multiindex from it, i.e. `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index, names=['a','b','c'])`.

Comment: If it's feasible, instead of returning two lists you might be better off returning a single list of tuples like `(key1, key2, key3, value)`, and doing something like `df = pd.DataFrame(single_list, columns=['a','b','c','d']).set_index(['a','b','c'])`.  Seems a bit cleaner than manually creating a multiindex.

Comment: Thanks for the input, it does seem cleaner.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I get an error making a dataframe from dictionary values.

Comment: Python 2.7, I believe you are probably using Python 3 (`dict.values` is a `view` object there). I guess this is something I would have to consider as well if I eventually want to support Python 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made memory profiling of 1M rows. The winning structure is to use array.array for every numerical index and a list for strings (147MB data and 310MB conversion to pandas).

According to Python manual

> Arrays are sequence types and behave very much like lists, except that
>   the type of objects stored in them is constrained.

They even have append method and most likely have very fast append speed.

Second place goes to two separate lists. (308MB and 450MB)

The other two options, using a dict and using a list with tuples of four, were the worst. Dict: 339MB, 524MB. List of four: 308MB, 514MB.

Here is the use of array.array:

```
In [1]: from array import array
In [2]: import gc
In [3]: import pandas as pd
In [4]: %load_ext memory_profiler
In [5]: a1=array("l",range(1000000))
In [6]: a2=array("l",range(1000000))
In [7]: a3=array("l",range(1000000))
In [8]: b=[str(x*111) for x in list(range(1000000))]
In [9]: gc.collect()
Out[9]: 0
In [10]: %memit a1,a2,a3,b
peak memory: 147.64 MiB, increment: 0.32 MiB
In [11]: %memit dfpair=pd.DataFrame(b,  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a1,a2,a3], names=['a','b','c']))
peak memory: 310.60 MiB, increment: 162.91 MiB
```

Here is the rest of the code (very long):

List of tuples of four:

```
In [1]: import gc
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: %load_ext memory_profiler
In [4]: a=list(zip(list(range(1000000)),list(range(1000000)),list(range(1000000))))
In [5]: b=[str(x*111) for x in list(range(1000000))]
In [6]: d2=[x+(b[i],) for i,x in enumerate(a)]
In [7]: del a
In [8]: del b
In [9]: gc.collect()
Out[9]: 0
In [10]: %memit d2
peak memory: 308.40 MiB, increment: 0.28 MiB
In [11]: %memit df = pd.DataFrame(d2, columns=['a','b','c','d']).set_index(['a','b','c'])
peak memory: 514.21 MiB, increment: 205.80 MiB
```

Dictionary:

```
In [1]: import gc
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: %load_ext memory_profiler
In [4]: a=list(zip(list(range(1000000)),list(range(1000000)),list(range(1000000))))
In [5]: b=[str(x*111) for x in list(range(1000000))]
In [6]: d = dict(zip(a, b))
In [7]: del a
In [8]: del b
In [9]: gc.collect()
Out[9]: 0
In [10]: %memit d
peak memory: 339.14 MiB, increment: 0.23 MiB
In [11]: %memit dfdict=pd.DataFrame(list(d.values()),  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys(), names=['a','b','c']))
peak memory: 524.10 MiB, increment: 184.95 MiB
```

Two arrays:

```
In [1]: import gc
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: %load_ext memory_profiler
In [4]: a=list(zip(list(range(1000000)),list(range(1000000)),list(range(1000000))))
In [5]: b=[str(x*111) for x in list(range(1000000))]
In [6]: gc.collect()
Out[6]: 0
In [7]: %memit a,b
peak memory: 307.75 MiB, increment: 0.19 MiB
In [8]: %memit dfpair=pd.DataFrame(b,  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(a, names=['a','b','c']))
peak memory: 459.94 MiB, increment: 152.19 MiB
```

Comment: Thanks! I also got that the dict did not perform as well as lists. I will look more into array, thanks for all the awesome pointers. I will post my findings as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the benchmarks using `memory_profiler`:

```
Filename: testdict.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4     66.2 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
     5                             def testdict():
     6
     7     66.2 MiB      0.0 MiB        d = {}
     8
     9    260.6 MiB    194.3 MiB        for i in xrange(0,1000000):
    10    260.6 MiB      0.0 MiB                d[(i,i,i)]=str(i)*3
    11
    12    400.2 MiB    139.6 MiB        dfdict=pd.DataFrame(d.values(),  index=
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys(), names=['a','b','c']))

Filename: testlist.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4     66.5 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
     5                             def testlist():
     6
     7     66.5 MiB      0.0 MiB        keyslist=[]
     8     66.5 MiB      0.0 MiB        valslist=[]
     9
    10    229.3 MiB    162.8 MiB        for i in xrange(0,1000000):
    11    229.3 MiB      0.0 MiB                keyslist.append((i,i,i))
    12    229.3 MiB      0.0 MiB                valslist.append(str(i)*3)
    13
    14    273.6 MiB     44.3 MiB        dflist=pd.DataFrame(valslist,  index=
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(keyslist, names=['a','b','c']))
```

For the same task and memory types, it does seem the dictionary implementation is not as memory efficient.

## Edit

For some reason, when I change the values to arrays of numbers (more representative of my data) I get very similar performance, does anyone know why this is happening?

```
Filename: testdict.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4     66.9 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
     5                             def testdict():
     6
     7     66.9 MiB      0.0 MiB        d = {}
     8
     9    345.6 MiB    278.7 MiB        for i in xrange(0,1000000):
    10    345.6 MiB      0.0 MiB                d[(i,i,i)]=[0]*9
    11
    12    546.2 MiB    200.6 MiB        dfdict=pd.DataFrame(d.values(),  index=
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys(), names=['a','b','c']))

Filename: testlist.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4     66.3 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
     5                             def testlist():
     6
     7     66.3 MiB      0.0 MiB        keyslist=[]
     8     66.3 MiB      0.0 MiB        valslist=[]
     9
    10    314.7 MiB    248.4 MiB        for i in xrange(0,1000000):
    11    314.7 MiB      0.0 MiB                keyslist.append((i,i,i))
    12    314.7 MiB      0.0 MiB                valslist.append([0]*9)
    13
    14    515.2 MiB    200.6 MiB        dflist=pd.DataFrame(valslist,  index=
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(keyslist, names=['a','b','c']))
```

Comment: The string in python remembers previous strings. So that "000" occupies the same memory as another "000". And it could be that "1000" is actually one byte linking to "000" string. Numbers could not do that.